# Google Cardboard SDK (Unity): How to play audio

Tags: android, audio, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I am new to Unity.  After adding the Google Cardboard prefabs, I added a new GameObject and added an AudioSource to that to play an mp3.  When I run the program in Unity I hear the audio.  When I build on an Android device (Samsung 5S), I do not hear the audio.  The device makes noises in other apps so the volume is up.

Is there a restriction on what audio can be played on the device, or am I doing something incorrect?

Comment: there must be something wrong with your audio source. make sure that the volume is 1, stereo pan is 0, spatial blend 0 (2D). Make sure that there is no if statements or platform specific code preventing it from playing (if you play it through code). Make sure audio listener is on on your Main Camera.

Comment: Audio listener on the main camera.  Those are the values on our audio source.  I tried a second Android device we have and same issue.